# How to use first path variable in another path?

Tags: go

In this code, I am trying to print the integer value in `main.go` file but it is not importing. Although I have given the whole path `"github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS/entrance"`. But it is showing me that this path cannot be imported. It suggested using `go get github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS/entrance`. If I use it, it gives me the following error.

**Error**

```
go get: module github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS/entrance: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/bilal/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/12d2f712035af4ad5a78f3899369cc7415a29cd446ddffd01c3052f757db17ff: exit status 128:
        remote: Repository not found.
        fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS/' not found
```

**next.go**

```
package entrance

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var integer = 3
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS/entrance"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println(integer)
}
```

Comment: You need to export and you need to package-qualify. What all of that means is explained in the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, you are clearly having trouble with even the basics of Go modules, so I am going to walk through it step by step. First, make a new, empty directory. I am going to use Windows paths, because that's what I use. Change as needed:

```
C:\PMS
```

Then go to that folder, and do this:

```
go mod init github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS
```

Then make a another folder:

```
C:\PMS\entrance
```

Then make `C:\PMS\entrance\next.go`:

```
package entrance

var Integer = 3
```

Then make `C:\PMS\entrance\entrance\main.go`:

```
package main
import "github.com/ibilalkayy/PMS/entrance"

func main() {
   println(entrance.Integer)
}
```

Then in the folder with `main.go`, do this:

```
go build
```